# Python equivalent of the double colon (::) operator in java

Tags: java, python, json, handler

What is the double colon(::) operator in java also known as method reference operator in Java equivalent in python ??

Syntax:

```
<Class name>::<method name>
```

Example:
 `"/absfds/dclckd/dsf: {
        "reference": false,
        "type": "object",
        "value": {
            "functionName": "",
            "artifactPath": "",
            "branch": "develop",
            "buildType": "",
            "buildCommand": "",
            "repository": "",
            "storageClass": "STANDARD_IA",
            "handler": "package along with class name::method"
        },
        "volatile": true`

The handler is inside a .json file which is accessing java files. How to write the handler when it is accessing python files. Does it remain the same ?

Comment: You should just be able to use a period `.` to reference a method, in either a class or a class instance.

Comment: There is no equivalent because there is no need: in Python, functions/methods are first-class objects. A function is an object just like an `int`, or a `list` or whatever. A method is simply a function that is an attribute of a class, so it is accessed the same way you access any attribute, `MyClass.some_method`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid JSON file, at least not in this format.

To get a reference to a method in Python, you just use its name but without `()`, eg.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv
<function getenv at 0x...>
>>> os.getenv('EDITOR')
'nvim'
>>> f = os.getenv
>>> f('EDITOR')
'nvim'
```

(ETA: it works the same way if `os` was a class, or an instance of a class.)